# Use an arbitrary object type to parse a MySql query (learning C# Reflection)

Tags: c#, mysql, parsing, reflection

I'm trying to gain a better understanding of Generics and Reflection on C#. As an exercise, I'm executing a MySql query and trying to parse its results as predefined Objects:

```
//FOR TABLE A 
public class ObjectType1
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public String name { get; set; }
    }

 //FOR TABLE B
public class ObjectType2
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public timestamp expirationDate  { get; set; }    
    }

 //FOR TABLE C 
public class ObjectType3
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public BigDecimal price  { get; set; }
    
    }
```

My goal would look like this:

```
List<ObjectType1> listObjectsA =  selectAndCast(tableNameA, ObjectType1)
List<ObjectType2> listObjectsB =  selectAndCast(tableNameB, ObjectType2)
List<ObjectType3> listObjectsC =  selectAndCast(tableNameC, ObjectType3)
```

My question is, how could I specify the desired object type as a parameter? (Already checked the similar questions here at S.O., but got compilation errors).

ANSWER TO THE QUESTION / WORKING CODE:

Thanks to @JosephDaSilva for this corrections

```
public List<T> selectAndCast<T>(string connStr, String query, int argTimeoutSecs) where T : new()
        {

            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);

            MySqlDataReader rdr = null;

            List<T> listaSalida = new List<T>();


            try
            {
                conn.Open();

                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);

                if (argTimeoutSecs != -1)
                {
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = argTimeoutSecs;
                }

                rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                //  Create a dictionary that contains each column name and a consecutive number. That number will be later  used to locate the column by its name.

                Dictionary<String, int> dictionaryColumnNameVsIndex = new Dictionary<String, int>();

                for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
                {
                    String nombreColumna = rdr.GetName(i);
                    dictionaryColumnNameVsIndex.Add(nombreColumna, i);
                }

                
                PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

                T destinationObject;

                while (rdr.Read())
                {

                    //  For each row obtained from the query execution, create a new instance of the Object

                    destinationObject = new T();


                    for (int i = 0; i < rdr.FieldCount; i++)
                    {

                        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
                        {

                            //  Check if the destination object contains a property with the same name.

                            if (dictionaryColumnNameVsIndex.ContainsKey(property.Name))
                            {

                                //  If it does, assign the value to said property.

                                PropertyInfo propertyToBeChanged = destinationObject.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name);

                                String newValue = rdr[dictionaryColumnNameVsIndex[property.Name]].ToString();

                                propertyToBeChanged.SetValue(destinationObject, newValue);
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //  After all rows have been processed, return the object list
                    listaSalida.Add(destinationObject);

                }

                return listaSalida;

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("Error when trying to SELECT: " + ex.ToString()); 
                return null;

            }
            finally
            {
                if (rdr != null)
                {
                    rdr.Close();
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a type parameter `T` in your `selectAndCast` method for the type of the object. Since you will need to create instances of the type, constrain the type parameter with `new()` which requires the type to have a parameterless constructor (all of your object types have one since there are no explicit constructors). So the `selectAndCast` method should be declared as:

```cs
public List<T> selectAndCast<T>(string tableName) where T : new() {
   // ...
}
```

To create an instance of `List<T>`, use:

```cs
List<T> listaSalida = new List<T>();
```

To create an instance of the type `T` (works because of the `new()` constraint):

```cs
T destinationObject = new T();
```

To get the properties of the type `T` (this should also be moved outside the read loop because it will always return the same list of properties every time):

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();
```

The generic method can be called like this:

```
List<ObjectType1> listObjectsA = selectAndCast<ObjectType1>(tableNameA);
```